# Only accept certain file types during PHP file upload

Tags: php

Got what I'm sure is a simple problem but can't seem to find a simple solution which works. I'm creating an image upload website and I want only JPEG's and PNG's to be the allowed file types. Here is the start of my PHP code which runs when a user clicks on the 'upload' button after selecting their file. After this I just have a long list of IF statements which all run and work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

if ($_FILES['filename']['name']['size']) {

```
    session_start(); 
    $name = $_FILES['filename']['name'];
    $size = $_FILES['filename']['size'];
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'];

    if($size < 2000000) {...
```

Comment: have you checked: $_FILES['filename']['type']

Comment: You can use regex (`"/\.(\w+)$/"`) to check the extension and then match it against an array of supported extensions.

Comment: @KoolKabin - With regards to what you suggested, can I simply say something like if($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") {... ?

Comment: @user1134548: definitely you can. but make sure you are adding or for gif, bmp and png files too if required.

Comment: So at the minute I have this but it won't let me upload any type of file.

if (($_FILES['filename']['name']['size'])
& ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")) {

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Got it sorted now. KoolKabin's way was the cleanest. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I think this will do

```
    $allowed_types =array('jpg','png')
    $userFile = $_FILES['filename']['name'];
    $error = null;

    // Get the file extension
    $extension = pathinfo($userFile, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    // Search the array for the allowed file type

    if (in_array($extension, $allowed_types, false) != true) {

        $error = "ERROR: ILLEGAL FILE TYPE";
        return $error; // or use  exit;
    }
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thanks! One tiny correction: first line needs a semicolon at the end.

Answer (score 1):

check the type attribute of uploaded file. Sample code from: 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

```
/*** 
    now verify the mime, i did not find 
    something more easy than verify the 
    'image/' ty^pe. if wrong tell it! 
***/ 

    if(!eregi('image/', $_FILES['attachement']['type'])) { 

      echo 'The uploaded file is not an image please upload a valide file!'; 

    } else {
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried this.. it helped me..

This could help you too..

```
<?php
$target_dir = "images/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {

        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, PNG, JPEG and GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```